# Query with multiple ancestors in Google App Engine(GAE) JAVA

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have two entities 'user' and 'comment'
I create **comments** and set ancestor path as **user**
I added 5 users and some comments per each user.

What I wanted to do is, filter out comments only for two users within one query with limit and offset

I have searched in Google App Engine documentation, but I couldn't find any answer for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for not finding anything is that this is not possible by design.

An ancestor query is always a query by id. If you need to find all children of multiple ancestors you have to add the parent id as an indexed column in your child entity and filter by that column.